# ¿como poner una imagen dentro de un popup y que este a su vez tenga la opción de zoom?

Tags: android

¿como poner una imagen dentro de un popup y que este a su vez tenga la opción de zoom?

He intentado con  `AlertDialog`, pero aún no logro tener los gestos,agradeceré su ayuda

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.sincon);
AlertDialog.Builder builder =
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).
                setMessage("").
                setCancelable(true).
                setPositiveButton("enviar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).
                setCancelable(true).
                setPositiveButton("enviar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).
                setPositiveButton("Cerrar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).
                setView(image);
builder.create().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

La alternativa más fácil que se me ocurre es crear un WebView que contenga la imagen y este añadirlo a tu AlertDialog, de esta forma solo se tendría que habilitar las funcionalidades de ZoomControls.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Title here");

    WebView wv = new WebView(this);
    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/drawable/", "<img src='imagen.png' />", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }
    });

    alert.setView(wv);
    alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alert.show();
```